# CRC32 integer hash to string

Tags: hash, lua, crc32

I was looking for a Lua implementation of CRC32 and stumbled upon this:
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/master/t/lib/CRC32.lua

However it returns the integer hash, how would I go about getting the string equivalent of it?

Using the input "something" it returns: 1850105976

Using an online CRC32 generator I get: "879fb991"

Comment: Should be `09DA31FB`

Comment: There exist at least [9 different CRC32 sums](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html)

Comment: I see, but that doesn't really answer my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many CRC-32 algorithms. You can find ten different CRC-32s documented in [this catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm). The Lua code you found and the online CRC32 you found (somewhere -- no link was provided) are different CRC-32s.

What you seem to mean by a "string equivalent" is the hexadecimal representation of the 32-bit integer. In Lua you can use `string.format` with the print format `%x` to get hexadecimal. For the example you gave, `1850105976`, that would be `6e466078`.

Your "online CRC32 generator" appears to be using the BZIP2 CRC-32, though it is showing you the bytes of the resulting CRC in reversed order (little-endian). So the actual CRC in that case in hexadecimal is `91b99f87`. The Lua code you found appears to be using the MPEG-2 CRC-32. The only difference between those is the exclusive-or with `ffffffff`. So in fact the exclusive-or of the two CRCs you got from the two different sources, `6e466078 ^ 91b99f87` is `ffffffff`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark!

Comment: @user1826176 You can also try: https://github.com/hjelmeland/luacrc32 (available via luarocks at https://luarocks.org/modules/hjelmeland/crc32)

Comment: @hjpotter92 That one looks much better. It is the more standard PKZip/ITU v.42 CRC-32, and the implementation appears to use real bit operations (shifts and exclusive-or) as opposed to the very slow implementations with arithmetic in the code linked in the question.